# Use latest curl version on docker

Tags: linux, docker, curl, dockerfile, debian

I've the following docker image

```
FROM debian:10.7

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends curl
```

when I run it and use `curl --version` I got version `7.64` but the latest is `7.74`
https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

How should I upgrade the curl to the latest version 7.74 ?
is there a way to do it?

Comment: Download the newest tarball or clone the repository and build manually.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - this is the only way? the `apt-get update` shouldnt handle it?

Comment: `apt-get` can handle any package but it has to be added to the repository first.

Comment: No, the `apt-get update` should not handle it. What you get from apt is dependent on the deb package repositories maintained by the developers of Debian. They do not (and indeed cannot) keep up with the frequent releases of multitudes of software packages that they provide. The only way to get the latest curl is either to find a custom package repo that specifically follows curl (not sure if such a repo exists) or to build curl yourself.

Comment: If you're only interested in curl, check out the existing [curl Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl).

Comment: @timsmelik - thanks, I need it with multiple things ...

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - could you provide an answer with example how to add curl ?

Comment: @BenoOdr: curl has to be added to the repository by Debian maintainers.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - I mean to my docker file...

Comment: Check out the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/curl/curl-docker/blob/master/alpine/latest/Dockerfile) for the official image to see how they install the latest version.

Comment: @timsmelik - thanks, do you know pherhaps if there is a shorter/simple way to do it? as you need to install python etc which a bit cumbersome

Comment: Check the answer below for a shorter example. I'm curious though, why do you need the latest version of curl? Isn't a relatively recent version (7.64) good enough for your purposes?

Comment: @timsmelik - there is a lot of secuirty issue with versions less than 7.73

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the downloaded packages directly to solve this problem by installing with the make command.

```
FROM debian:10.7

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends wget build-essential libcurl4 && \
    wget https://curl.se/download/curl-7.74.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf curl-7.74.0.tar.gz && cd curl-7.74.0 && \
    ./configure && make && make install
```

Note that it requires running ./configure.

After installation curl will work perfectly in the version you need, in this case, version 7.74.0.

If you want to optimize your container, remove the build-essential package, it alone will consume more than 200MB of storage. To do this, add at the end of the compilation:

```
apt-get autoremove build-essential
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! , what does it mean to run `./configure` ?

Comment: Just pay attention on last line. It's necessary for make command successfully.

Comment: `
RUN wget https://curl.se/download/curl-7.74.0.tar.gz && \
        tar -xvf curl-7.74.0.tar.gz && cd curl-7.74.0 && \
        ./configure && make && make install
`
This is can also be used on alpine.

Answer (score 1):

You could clone curl source code from Git and build and install it
manually in your Dockerfile like that:

```
FROM debian:10.7

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends autoconf libtool automake make git

RUN GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 git clone https://github.com/curl/curl --depth 1
RUN cd curl && ./buildconf && ./configure && make -j$(nproc) install && \
    echo /usr/local/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf && ldconfig
```

After `docker run`:

```
root@d7ea28ad22e2:/# curl --version
curl 7.75.0-DEV (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.75.0-DEV
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap mqtt pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile UnixSockets
```

Comment: Sorry, I was able to handle it, however currently its dev can we change it to release version?\

Comment: I mean like this https://github.com/curl/curl/releases/tag/curl-7_74_0

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I ran into several issues with SSL and libs. The following changes I made fixes all of the issues I ran into:

```
RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install -y wget build-essential libssl-dev && \
    wget https://curl.se/download/curl-8.1.2.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf curl-8.1.2.tar.gz && \ 
    cd curl-8.1.2 && \ 
    ./configure --with-ssl && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl && \
    ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Curl on Alpine Linux is available from the following link:

https://github.com/curl/curl-docker/blob/master/alpine/latest/Dockerfile